# Why is the correlation coefficient of these subsections of this dataset indicating a much weaker correlation than the whole dataset?

Tags: regression, correlation, data-visualization, regression-coefficients

I have a dataset which includes household income against expenditure. The correlation coefficient of the dataset is 0.7064 which indicates a strong positive correlation. Here's a graph for it: [image]

Now I split this into two subsections and I'll include the graph for both of them now:
[image]

[image]

Now the correlation coefficient for these two are 0.4551 and 0.4784 respectively. I don't understand why this is the case, surely if the whole dataset indicates a strong positive correlation than these subsets should show something similar? If the subsets each have a weak positive correlation, why does having the two next to eachother make the correlation so much stronger?

Comment: Sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

> Surely if the whole dataset indicates a strong positive correlation
> than these subsets should show something similar?

Not at all. In fact, there can be 0 or even negative correlation in the subsets and a strong correlation in the whole data set. Here is an extreme example with made up data:

```
set.seed(1234)

x1 <- rnorm(1000, -5, 1)
x2 <- rnorm(1000, 5, 1)
y1 <- -1*x1 + rnorm(1000)
y2 <- -1*x2 + rnorm(1000) + 50

x <- c(x1,x2) 
y <- c(y1,y2)

cor(x1, y1) #-0.69
cor(x2, y2)  #-0.70
cor(x, y) #097

plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand a bit more now, but of course the example you gave is quite extreme, with the one's i presented above, the correlation, at least visually to me seem very similar when comparing each subset with the main set, so I'm not certain why there should be such a big difference in the correlation coefficient, is it because the sample size is alot smaller?

Comment: No., it's because the correlation is different.  That happens. There really isn't anything that surprising in it.

Comment: Okay, thank you, sorry if this is a silly question, but is there any kind of conclusion that you can draw from this about the relationship between the two variables? for example if the opposite was the case and the subsets both had a strong positive correlation what would be the difference in terms of what you could say about the data? or is it arbitrary in and of itself and would need other indicators in addition?

Comment: There is some nonlinearity in the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing surprising about what you describe. I would be more worried about the fact that you seem to be reaching a "detection limit" around an income of 1200 and an expenditure around 1200 (this "frame" of data points on the top and right sides of your plot).
I would expect this to strongly bias what you are trying to detect.
Maybe you are arbitrarily attributing the value 1200 to measures superior or equal to 1200 for income as well as expenditure ?